# append function in ajax is not append image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm using ASP.Net MVC, I try to append img in ajax to div in Html but it is not added I'm sure the path is correct, everything except img is added correctly.

```
SetData.append('<img src="~/images/female-worker.png" alt=""/>'); //not append 
SetData.append('<p> append correctly</p>');
```

Comment: Remove the leading `~`

Answer (score 0):

I removed `~` and its working

```
SetData.append('<img src="/images/female-worker.png" alt=""/>'); //not append
```